# How to check if there are any iinstances of particular class in the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have class a `Client` which derivies from `Person`.
In the `Seed` method when I want to populate table with `Person` object I ask:

```
  if (!context.Person.Any())
```

I used Table Per Hierarchy mapping, there is discriminator in the table.

How to ask if there are any Clients in `Person` table?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
if (context.Person.Any(p => p is Client))
```

which will return true if `context.Person` is an enumeration of `Person` objects, and any of them is a `Client` object. If this is not exactly what you need, I hope at least it will tell you enough to figure the rest on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx) method which limits the query to only results of a specific type:

```
if (!context.Persons.OfType<Client>().Any())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able the use the [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx) extension menthod.
So you would have some like:

```
 if (!context.Person.OfType<Client>.Any()) {
    //do something here
 }
```